# how to transform byte[] value of blob field in mysql to insert into statement

Tags: java, mysql

I want to select data from a mysql table, and then generate a sql script file for importing to another db.

The value type of blob in mysql is byte array in java. I have try to use `new String(byte[], Charset)` to transform it to String, using all charsets that java support. It can import successfully, but the imported value is incorrect. All the generated strings are not equal to what SQLyog generates.

how can i do?

Comment: Why do you care what SQLyog generates?

Comment: what SQLyog generates can import correctly

Comment: "another db" is another mysql instance? It is important detail as blob semantics differs between databases. Also your "script" is Java program or txt file with sql statements?

Comment: Another db is also a mysql instance. And the script file is a text file with "insert into" statements which represent blob value in string. The requirement is to export data from a public server to a private server.